OpenID (elytron-oidc-client) with .ear or subdeployment in WildFly 26
Because i have no solution for the main-problem (SSO with OpenID), i tried to use the authentication from the main deployment.
But this is an ear-Deployment and the subsystem "elytron-oidc-client" seems only supports war-Deployments.
When i set an ear-Deployment in <secure-deployment name="main-app.ear">, nothing is logged. With war-Deployments it works with the following info:
WFLYOIDC0002: Elytron OIDC Client subsystem override for deployment 'branding.war'
I tried also the name with a subdeployment like "main-app.ear!login.war", but with no success.
Anyone experience with the elytron-oidc-client and use SSO or subdeployments?
